# Regarding significance of spectral variation under algebraic operations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sp.spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I have been reading the paper [Determining elements in $C^∗$-algebras through spectral properties](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022247X13003181?token=6D5ABCE5230D986347E3FAA0DAEAD08C10F40FB31B5001D8CEF569C6A27F48E5F47D5CA96C6468BD6B8012083F567663&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220526162409).
The paper discusses about what would be the relation be between two elements $a$ and $b$ of a Banach algebra $A$ which satisfy $\sigma(ax) \subset \sigma(bx)$ or $\sigma(a+x) \subset \sigma(b+x)$ for all $x \in A$.
Can anyone tell what exactly is the motivation behind this problem, what are its applications? Why should this problem be settled for any Banach algebra?
The most I could find is that the authors say the problem is motivated by the Kaplansky problem.

Comment: I can't say anything on the actual question, but generally speaking, the fact that a problem is discussed in a published paper is scant evidence for there being any motivation for it.

Comment: It might be interesting to reverse the question: what was *your* motivation for reading the paper?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I personally love this theory as its neat and elegant. My question arose as to how to explain to mathematicians of another area as to why this theory is significant.